# Java: Two classes with main methods accessing the same third class

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I have written a Java project, where two classes have main methods (in my case one class is a server, the other one is a client and they are communicating, but this doesn't realy matter). I would like to know, what behaviour I should expect, if both classes access one and the same third class like in this example:

```
class A{

public static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();;

}

class B{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        A.list.add(String.valueOf("Hello"));
        System.out.println(list.size());
    }

}

class C{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        A.list.add(String.valueOf("World"));
        System.out.println(list.size());
    }

}
```

What would I get if I first run the main method of class B and then the main method of class C? I would expect that the main method of class C does NOT see the list-element added by the main method of class B, in other words, it would print "1" just like the main method of B which ran before, but i'm not sure. Is this correct?  So do the two main methods see the changes the other one has made to class A? Or does each main method somehow have a "version of class A for itself"?

Thanks for your help!

Greetings,
Daniel

Comment: Do you mean "in the same process", or running the two in separate JVMs? It's not really clear how you're executing these, which is *crucial* to predicting what will happen...

Comment: I created two bat-files to run those classes. The first file has the content (using the name of this example) "java A" and the other one "java B".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is running in two different JVM. There will two different instance of class with respective to there JVM. Two JVM does not shared memory or anything.So it will not impact any of your class execution output.If you will run two thread in single JVM then synchronization issue will occur.

Answer (score 1):

running each class will be in a different JVM instance ( process) so basically they are two different programs and has nothing to do with each other